# Append a css shape to my <li> item?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use css shapes instead of images wherever it seems appropriate.

Currently i'm aiming to add a white triangular shape to the end of my `<li>` links like so:

[image]

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDwaK/) for you to tweak.

I've been with it for a while but as a novice developer I haven't been able to find an approach! The navigation bar stuff is at the bottom of the css and the html. I'm trying to keep the result responsive by using em and percent where possible and really this triangular shapes height needs to be the same as the nav_option class (which can double in height if the texts gets knocked onto the next line by window adjustment)

Any advice / solutions? Much appreciated!

Edit: if this is not possible due to my relative font-size then please detail an alternative solution? Suggesting the use of Javascript is helpful but a bit to vague for a novice like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the border hack to make this shape, the measurement you need want work with, font-size, cannot apply. You will need a JavaScript solution to detect line-wrap and adjust the border dimensions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The font size is relative with font-size of ascendant element, doesn't with width or height of parent element. So, to use responsive font-size, try to use some jquery plugin (FitText) or build a your JS.

http://fittextjs.com/